# regular expression to match exact string

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

this is probably very simple, but I would like to match for

```
abc
```

and exclude

```
abcd
```

anything I try picks up both cases, but I only want the first. what regular expression ignored any case with abcd?

thanks

Comment: What language are you using the regex in?  It should just be `abc`

Answer (score 0):

Several solutions:

abc(?!d)

with a negative lookahead assertion *(i.e. "not followed by")*

or

(abc)[^d]

with the result in capture group.

Comment: @EvertonAgner: good edit, but in this case this is the OP problem.

Comment: I think OP he means match `abc` but don't match an `abcd`.